# Upgraded From TFS 2010 to TFS 2013, How do I get the new work item templates

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I just upgraded to TFS 2013 from 2010 and ran the 'Configure Features' wizard for my team project [as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx).

Via the <kbd>TEAM</kbd> -> <kbd>New Work Item</kbd> menu in VS2013, I can see the new categories ('Feature', 'Test'). However, the only available State options to select from are 'Active' and 'Closed'

If I create a brand new team project, I see 2 additional states: 'New' & 'Removed'.  The new work item window also looks very different.

Is there something else I need to do in order to see this new work item window when working with my original team project that was created with TFS 2010?

UPDATE (exported xml)

TFS 2010 Project: http://pastebin.com/Ptdz9PZN
TFS 2013 Project: http://pastebin.com/AfigNw7Z

Comment: To help you better, can you export the procesconfig, categories, and the work item definition (of the mismatching items) of the newly created project and the project you've upgraded? You can use `witadmin exportcategories`, `witadmin exportprocessconfig` and `witadmin exportwitd` to get the definition files. If you could post these; it would allow us to see what your situation looks like.

Answer (score 4):

When you ran Configure Features, which Process Template did you use as the "Template" process template. The default may not have been the one you were expecting. If you haven't customized your process template heavily, you can "upgrade" your old team project by pushing a standard 2013 process template in the same flavor over it.

You can also overwrite the specific work item types using the witadmin commandline.

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:TeamProject /f:Feature.xml
```

If you want the default template use the Visual Studio Process Template Manager (<kbd>Team</kbd> -> <kbd>Team Project Collection Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Process Template Manager</kbd>) select the template you need and click the <kbd>download</kbd> button.

You might also need to push an updated `ProcessTemplateConfiguration.xml` and/or `categories.xml` using the respective `witadmin importprocessconfig` and `witadmin importcategories` commands.

You mentioned that you've selected MSF Agile, these are the states you should be able to see:
[image]

When comparing both outputs you'll see that the definition of `Task` has a much more extensive state model defined in the 2013 version, both in the definition of the form, as well as in the processconfig. You can resolve this by importing the work item definition from the 2013 project over your 2010 one using the `importwitd` command.

After updating the Work Item Type Definition, push the processconfig of the 2013 project over the 2010 one. When comparing the two work item definitions for Task, the list of fields is the same across both projects, so you can safely push the new definition over the old one. It looks like someone (in the past) has changed the state model for Task in your 2010 project.

See also:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh500409.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I ran the wizard I selected "MSF for Agile Software Development 2013.4" which is the same option I selected when I created the new team project.  The original team project from TFS 2010 did not have any customizations.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you should do now, as we do not know exactly what process template you had before the upgrade, which you picked in the upgrade wizard and what your installation decided to merge together. Simplest solution would be to import the correct work item type definitions or to re-do the upgrade (but that requires you to be able to restore to your pre-upgrade state). You might need to manually adjust the workflow of your work items, since these were made more liberal with the introduction of the agile tools.

Comment: The process template before the upgrade was the "MSF For Agile Software Development 5.0" (or whichever version was the default that came with TFS 2010).  This is a sandbox installation before we move forward with the real upgrade so I can mess around with it at will.

Comment: I will try to import the new State types manually but I'm confused as to why only part of the process was updated since I'm able to work with the new "Feature" work item type in the TFS 2010 team project.

Comment: The "upgrade" wizard enables the new features, but leaves your template alone with a few other respects, such as state model and form layout.  It's the "enable new features"  wizard, not the "upgrade to 2013.4" wizard so to say.

Comment: Got it. I have updated my question with the exported xml as requested, thanks.

Comment: You should be able to safely push the definition of Task from the 2013 project over the upgraded 2010 project. After that push the processconfig from the 2013 version as well.

Comment: @jesseehouwing I'm assuming I need to do this for each work item type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67935/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-thiag0).